# How to get the line of a token in parse rules?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have searched everywhere and can't find a solution. I am new to ANTLR and for an assignment, I need to print out (using similar syntax that I have below) an error message when my parser comes across an unidentified token with the line number and token. The [documentation for antlr4](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/actions.md) says line is an attribute for Token objects that gives "[t]he line number on which the token occurs, counting from 1; translates to a call to `getLine`. Example: `$ID.line`."

I attempted to implement this in the following chunk of code:

```
not_valid : not_digit { System.out.println("Line " + $not_digit.line + " Contains  Unrecognized  Token " $not_digit.text)}; 
not_digit :  ~( DIGIT );
```

But I keep getting the error

`unknown attribute line for rule not_digit in $not_digit.line`

My first thought was that I was applying an attribute for a lexer *token* to a parser *rule* because the documentation splits Token and Rule attributes into two different tables. so then I change the code to be:

```
not_valid : NOT_DIGIT { System.out.println("Line " + $NOT_DIGIT.line + " Contains  Unrecognized  Token " $NOT_DIGIT.text)}; 
NOT_DIGIT :  ~ ( DIGIT ) ;
```

and also

```
not_valid : NOT_DIGIT { System.out.println("Line " + $NOT_DIGIT.line + " Contains  Unrecognized  Token " $NOT_DIGIT.text)}; 
NOT_DIGIT :  ~DIGIT ;
```

like the example in the documentation, but both times I got the error

`rule reference DIGIT is not currently supported in a set`

I'm not sure what I am missing. All my searches turn up how to do this in Java outside of the parser, but I need to work in the action code (I think that's what it is called) in the parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A block like `{ ... }` is called an *action*. You embed target specific code in it. So if you're working with Java, then you need to write Java between `{` and `}`

A quick demo:

```
grammar T;

parse
 : not_valid EOF
 ;

not_valid
 : r=not_digit
   {
     System.out.printf("line=%s, charPositionInLine=%s, text=%s\n",
         $r.start.getLine(),
         $r.start.getCharPositionInLine(),
         $r.start.getText()
     );
   }
 ;

not_digit
 :  ~DIGIT
 ;

DIGIT
 : [0-9]
 ;

OTHER
 : ~[0-9]
 ;
```

Test it with the code:

```java
String source = "a";
TLexer lexer = new TLexer(CharStreams.fromString(source));
TParser parser = new TParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
parser.parse();
```

which will print:

```
line=1, charPositionInLine=0, text=a
```

Comment: Thank you! One question, though. What is the function of `start`? Could you point me to documentation on it?

Comment: You're welcome. Every parser rule/context, has a `start`- and `end` token: https://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/ParserRuleContext.html